# Identifying different permutations of some field in Excel holding others constant

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2016, I have a worksheet with five columns of headings (A through E) and many rows of data. I'm trying to find entries that have the same data for columns A through D and to identify what the different versions of the data in column E are given the data in A through D.

So far I have created a pivot table that has columns A through D as rows and the distinct count of E is shown as the value. This allows me to see which combinations of A through D have more than one possible E value but I'm not sure how to retrieve what those values of E actually are.

In the end I would like to populate a separate worksheet with all the possible A-D combinations paired with all of their possible E values. Is this possible to do with a pivot table or would I need VBA? Should I consider a different approach?

Any help is appreciated. I've attached an example screenshot which may make my problem statement more clear. In the example the first two rows would have the same A-D values and the possible E values would be 3 and 5.

[image]

Comment: Are the values in A,B,C,D enumerable within their columns? i.e. if you have `color` in A, `fruit` in B, `price` in C, `store` in D? or might you have the same value in A as you might find in B? Is their order important?

Comment: columns A,B,C,D all indicate different things as in your first statement (color for A, fruit in B, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just expanding on JaredT's great idea.

In **F2** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A2:D2)
```

and copy downward.*(use concatenate if you don't have textjoin)*.  Then copy column **F** and PasteSpecialValues into column **G**.

Then remove duplicates from column **G**

We can now gather all the column **E** items associated with cols **A** through **D**.  In **H2** enter the array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($F$2:$F$99=G2,$E$2:$E$99,""))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This is an array formula.  **Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I want to do. However when I copy the exact formulas and test file in your example, row H does not do what your screen shows. There doesn't seem to be a way to attach a picture to a comment but H2 contains all values of E separated by commas and the rest of H remains blank. Any idea why that is? When I created row G I simply copy and pasted values and then did a remove duplicates under the Data tab.

Comment: @KyleJones  **My error, not yours** ...........see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: You did mention it was an array formula, thanks you've been very helpful!

Comment: That's why I always show array-entered formulas with the braces surrounding them. That's a visual reminder when you copy-paste that you need to remove them and array-enter the formula.

Comment: @robinCTS  Very good idea!  I usually show the braces in the picture and include the instructions in the text.  I forgot the text this time.

Answer (score 0):

### A simple solution

The simplest, if perhaps the ugliest, option is to add a helper column, maybe call it `group`, which is just a concatenation of columns A->D; e.g. `=CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2)` which may leave you with a value of `RedApple$1PigglyWiggly`. Obviously you can add delimiters to make it easier on the eyes. It would be a simple operation to group on this field in your pivot table.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good idea. After I've done this how would I go about identifying each possible E value for each of my `group` entries?